# Why Pytorch is slower than Tensorflow in read data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch

I tried two version code for iterate MNIST data to compare the elapsed time.

**Pytorch version**

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
import torch
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    datasets.MNIST('~/data', train=True, download=True,
                   transform=transforms.Compose([
                       transforms.ToTensor(),
                       # transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                   ])),
    batch_size=30000, shuffle=True,pin_memory=True,num_workers=4)
tic = time.time()
for epoch in range(0, 5):
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        continue
toc=time.time()
print('elapsed time:',toc-tic)
```

**Tensorflow 2.x version**

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "0"
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import datasets
import time
(xs, ys), (xs_, ys_) = datasets.mnist.load_data()
# print('datasets:', xs.shape, ys.shape, xs.min(), xs.max())
xs = tf.convert_to_tensor(xs, dtype=tf.float32) / 255.
db = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((xs, ys))
db = db.batch(30000)
tic = time.time()
for epoch in range(5):
    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(db):
        continue
toc = time.time()
print('elapsed time:', toc - tic)
```

And the result are TF elapsed 2s and Pytorch elapsed 15s.
So, why Pytorch is slower than Tensorflow in read data?
Am I setting it wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Shijia li,

You do everything correctly, it is just less fast code used in Pytorch (perhaps for a reason).

I looked into Pytorch source code and found the following:

1. `train_loader` generates indices for each batch(30000-long list)
2. `train_loader`indices to fetcher.
3. Fetcher collects data from the dataset, but it only does it one record at a time, in cycle called by line 44 in [fetch.py](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py) module:

`data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]`

*I suspect that this is the main source of difference with TF - it may be producing whole batch as a single slice in one optimized operation (vs. Python cycle in Torch)*

4. data gets compacted from list of tuples of tensors into two large tensors by `collate_fn` and delivered to the user.

If you want to accelerate your code - convert the data into Tensors (equivalent of transforms), then generate the indices yourself and get slices of the data and targets without calling the loader. Or pack the resulting tensors into TensorDataset which should be much faster than VisionDataset (used for MNIST).

Someone at Pytorch development team may want to take a look at this.

Comment: This is not exactly appels and oranges: Pytorch's `train_loader ` performs transformations at the time of loading, while in your TF example the transformation is made in advance. The question to Torch team is whether it is possible to apply transformations faster to the whole batches, in some vectorized way.

Comment: See https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/42405#issuecomment-670971616 

The main slowness comes from the conversion from Tensor -> PIL Image -> back to Tensor. We can solve this via adding new parameters into MNIST dataset (and other dataset as well if needed).